# R Decile percentage plotting

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, bigdata, data-analysis

I have a data frame from a home income poll that looks like this:

```
ID       Income      Expense
001      2389.9      1400.5
003      5499.3      2309.2
..       ..          ..
```

*this is an example, the actual one has over 5k observations

I would like to be able to :

1. Plot the decile distribution by income only.
2. Create a variable wich asigns the tenth of the distribution by income only each Home is in.

1) I already tried this but it is not what I want, I'd like to know the percentage of homes in each tenth:

```
> Deciles<-quantile(DF$Income, prob = seq(0, 1, length = 11), type = 5)
> Deciles
        0%        10%        20%        30%        40%        50%        60% 
    231.89    9024.48   13308.24   16945.15   21071.38   25661.58   31607.07 
       70%        80%        90%       100% 
  40360.98   52927.98   77926.47 1634433.60
```

2) For the second part im looking to get something like this:

```
ID       Income      Expense   Decile
001      2389.9      1400.5    3
003      5499.3      2309.2    5
009      2245.0      1789.2    3
..       ..          ..        ..
```

Thanks!

Comment: try `as.integer` to your Deciles

Comment: When you say "I already tried this but it is not what I want:", you should explain *why* it's not what you want - how does it differ from your desired output?

Comment: @nrussell Thanks! What i want two know is  the ammount of homes in each tenth

Comment: isn't the percentage of homes in each tenth always 10%?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking if there is a function that is the inverse of the quantile, scaled and ceilinged to return the decile number (1-10) for each observation in a distribution.  You could use `ecdf` or you could write your own.  Mine looks like this:

```
# using my convention, decile 1 is highest value.  Swap -x for x if you want to change it
get_decile <- function(x) ceiling(10*rank(-x, ties.method="random") / length(x))
```

And you could plot the mean income by decile with something like:

```
# reproducible example!
your_df <- data.frame(id=1:1e3,
                      income=rnorm(1e3,5e4,2e4), 
                      expense=rnorm(1e3, 3e4, 1e4))

your_df$income_decile <- get_decile(your_df$income)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(your_df, aes(x=income_decile, y=income)) + 
    stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line") +
     scale_x_reverse(breaks=1:10)
```

[image]

Comment: why not use `ntile()` ? this is also one method of deciling, isn't it?

Comment: @ l_m_ what is `ntile()`?

Comment: it is a function used for deciling in R